# Trying to create a veiw where table 1 data is stored differently

Tags: mysql

aaiaflat_final

```
ID   Data  
1    [2,96,801]
```

Engine_willie2

```
ID   Data  Eng  
1    2     3.0  
1    96    4.0  
1    801   4.6  
1    999   5.0
```

---

```
Select  
Engine_willie2.ID,  
(  
CASE   
WHEN Engine_willie2.Data = aaiaflat_final.Data   
THEN Engine_willie.Data END  
)   
AS Data,  
(  
CASE   
WHEN Engine_willie2.Data = aaiaflat_final.Data   
THEN Engine_willie.Eng END  
)   
AS Eng  

FROM aaiaflat_final  

Left Join Engine_willie2 ON   
Engine_willie2.ID = aaiaflat_final.ID  

WHERE  

aaiaflat_final.ID <> ''
```

---

I would like the query to look like this

ACES_Query

```
ID   Data  Eng   
1    2     3.0  
1    96    4.0  
1    801   4.6
```

I'm not sure how to parse the [2,96,801] in the aaiaflat_final table as the query works fin if the Data is 2 or any other exact matching data to the data column in Engine_willie2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining the tables on `id`, using `replace()` to get rid of the brackets and then `find_in_set()` produces the desired result from the sample data.

```
SELECT e.id,
       e.data,
       e.eng
       FROM engine_willie2 e
            INNER JOIN aaiaflat_final a
                       ON a.id = e.id
       WHERE find_in_set(e.data, replace(replace(a.data, '[', ''), ']', ''));
```